# Какой аналог getComputedStyle.style.height для jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Какой аналог getComputedStyle.style.height для jquery?

Comment: Простите, а что вам мешает использовать getComputedStyle.style.height без jquery?

Comment: Что в этой схеме забыл `.style`?

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (var s of [".a", ".b"]) {
  console.log(
    s,
    getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(s)).height,
    $(s).height(),
    $(s).css('height')
  )
}
```

```css
.b {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.a, .b {
  height: 3em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```